# How do I override indent/html.vim's attribute indent behavior

Tags: vimscript, indentation

### Stated Purpose

I'm trying to override Vim's HTML attribute indent behavior. This question is specific to `ft=html`.

Vim has always inserted too many spaces when indenting HTML:

```html
<div>
    <div style="
                background-color: red;
                ">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd rather Vim insert fewer indentation characters when indenting attribute strings:

```html
<div>
    <div style="
        background-color: red;
    ">
    </div>
</div>
```

The indent of the `">` line would be nice to have, but it's not necessary.

**Caveat:** Vim will indent the `<div>` with the attribute differently if its start tag is on the first line of the file.

### What I've tried

The code in [indent/html.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/99d19438cabaf13074229d9a32e3a4af9ce98744/runtime/indent/html.vim#L921-L923) seems to indicate that I can override how many spaces attributes are indented by declaring a my own function `b:html_indent_tag_string_func`:

```
" indent/html.vim line 921
if exists('b:html_indent_tag_string_func')
    return b:html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)
endif
```

**Try 1:** I tried adding `function! b:html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)` in `~/.vim/ftplugin/html/vars.vim`, but that's a syntax error:

```
E884: Function name cannot contain a colon: b:html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)
```

**Try 2:** I also tried `function! html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)`, another syntax error:

```
E128: Function name must start with a capital or "s:": html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)
```

**Try 3:** Then I tried using a variable in the `b:` space:

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/html/vars.vim
function! Html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)
    return shiftwidth() + indent(a:lnum - 1)
endfunction
let b:html_indent_tag_string_func='Html_indent_tag_string_func'
```

However this always sets the indent to 0 without errors printed. I found out that this is because `b:html_indent_tag_string_func` is not `:call`-able; running `:echo b:html_indent_tag_string_func(3)` gives the error:

```
E1085: Not a callable type: b:html_indent_tag_string_func
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. One can turn a function into a first-class datatype using `let var = function(<name>)`:

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/html/vars.vim
function! s:my_html_indent_tag_string_func(lnum)
    return shiftwidth() + indent(a:lnum - 1)
endfunction
let b:html_indent_tag_string_func=function('s:my_html_indent_tag_string_func')
```